# check box not showing check Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have a parent model that accepts child attributes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

accepts_nested_attributes_for :spec

attr_accessible :name, :spec_attributes
```

In the view I have a form that gets information for 3 models. I use a generic form_tag.

```
<% form_tag(action)  do %>
.
.
.
    <% fields_for "user[spec_attributes]" do |spec_form|%>
    <%= spec_form.check_box :alert_greeting %> 
    <%= spec_form.label :alert_greeting, "Email me when new greetings are posted" %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

In the Controller

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

   do something.
   end
```

The database is getting updated and the all seems to be working.

However when I go back to the form to edit again, even though the value for the checkbox is showing 1 the check box is not checked.

Any ideas as to how to show the checkbox as being checked when it is supposed to be?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try with adding checked option with checking the value of parameter :alert_greeting

Comment: How are you seeing that the value of the check box is '1'?  Is this on the new form or just that the data base value is stored as 1.

Comment: When I view the source I see that the value=1 but the hidden field is set to 0. I also see it in the params passed in the terminal and in the database. I just don't understand why its not showing on the form if the value=1 ????

Comment: Also when I look at the parameters passed I see that the value is 1 and I also see it in the database.

Comment: The reason you are seeing a check box with value=1 and a hidden field with value=0 is that this is how Rails handle checkboxes -- it creates a hidden field so that if the checkbox isn't selected, a value is still submitted to the server (checkboxes don't normally send any data if they're not checked).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the specific `spec` record that is within the user you're calling.  Try changing

```
<% fields_for "user[spec_attributes]" do |spec_form|%>
```

to

```
<% fields_for @user.spec do |spec_form|%>
```

You'll need to make sure that you have a non-nil spec object built for the user (but not necessarily saved) in your edit controller action.

Comment: Thanks Brian. It seems when I do that the parameters generated are:Parameters: {"@user.spec"=>{"alert_greeting"=>"0"}. However I want to get params = { :user => { :name => 'Jack', :spec_attributes => { :alert_greeting => '1' } }  If I don't get it the parameters in that form then the database does not seem to get updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do attributes and nested attributes using two `fields_for` calls like this:

```
<%= form_tag(action) do %>
  ... other form tags ...
  <%= fields_for :user, @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= f.fields_for :spec do |s| %>
      <%= s.check_box :alert_greeting %> 
      <%= s.label :alert_greeting, "Email me when new greetings are posted" %> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are grabbing data from 3 models -- I'll update my answer to account for that.

Comment: Dude your a rock star. Thanks I think that is the trick. I will try it and get back to you.